# How can I make a query with the result of the previous query?

Tags: php, mysqli

This is a example of my code for made a query to the db:

```
$query_db = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT DATA FROM db_table WHERE data = ?');
$query_db->bind_param('s', $data);
$query_db->execute();
$query_db->store_result();
$query_db->bind_result($result_query1);
$query_db->fetch();
$query_db->close();
```

I have the next problem, if I want to make a query with the `$result_query1`, I should use the same code I posted above.

Comment: You're selecting the same column that you're specifying in the `WHERE` clause. What's the point of this? It will just return the same value of `$data`.

Comment: @Barmar It is a example of my problem, obious on my db This have logic, I need do the same query but with the result of the previous query result, I dont know If I xplain good

Comment: Why can't you put the result of the previous query in the bind_param? `$query_db->bind_param('ss', $result_query1, $data2)`

Comment: @Barmar Because I must select X data from the db, and with the result of the first data I must select other X data, and then other X data always with the result of the previous query

Comment: I still don't understand why it won't work. It seems like you've left out too much detail from the question. Please post a MCVE showing what you're really trying to do.

Comment: Usually if you want to use the results of a previous query in another query, the right solution is to join the tables into a single query.

Comment: @Barmar I dont need join to other table, I must do exactly the same query but with the previous result, I wil try explain you now better

Comment: Show sample data and the desired result.

Comment: You probably need to loop through all the rows returned by the first query. You're just processing the first row without a loop.

Comment: @Barmar I need to create 10 variables that will store 10 queries from the database, let's say that the 10 queries have something in common like an id, then I have the first id so I can do the first query, but to do the second query I need to do it with the result of the previous one in order to give value to the variables with the result of the queries

Comment: Put them in an array.

Comment: Are you trying to process hierarchical data?

Comment: @Barmar Let's take the example of saving the names of 10 relatives with the same DNA

Comment: That sounds like it should be a self-join. `SELECT t1.* FROM db_table AS t1 JOIN db_table AS t2 ON t1.dna = t2.dna WHERE t2.name = 'Fred'`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your time But I cant get it

Comment: If you won't edit the question to add the necessary clarifications, we can't help you. I'm just guessing what you're really trying to do.

Comment: @Barmar I will update now

Comment: @Barmar Please see now

Comment: @Barmar Should I write some more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop.

```
$all_results = [];
$data = 1;
$query_db = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT id FROM db_table WHERE common_data = ?');
$query_db->bind_param('s', $data);
$query_db->bind_result($result_query);
while (true) {
    $query_db->execute();
    if (!$query_db->fetch()) {
        break;
    }
    $all_results[] = $result_query;
    $data = $result_query;
}
print_r($all_results);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this few lines into a function and make parameter and than reclusion or if it's fixed number of SQLs than simple FOR

```
function loadData($previousData) {
    $query_db = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT DATA FROM db_table WHERE data = ?');
    $query_db->bind_param('s', $previousData);
    $query_db->execute();
    $query_db->store_result();
    $query_db->bind_result($result_query);
    $query_db->fetch();
    $query_db->close();
    return $result_query;
}

$dataSQL1 = loadData($data);
$dataSQL2 = loadData($dataSQL1);
$dataSQL3 = loadData($dataSQL2);
...
$dataSQLX = loadData($dataSQLX);
```